# Are Normal Stress Differences in Newtonian Fluids Equal?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain

I was reading about normal stress differences in the context of Non-Newtonian fluids. There was a remark that the normal stress differences in Non-Newtonian fluids are not equal whereas the normal stress differences in Newtonian fluids are equal. I can't figure out why the normal stress differences in a Newtonian fluid should be equal. Can anyone highlight a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general they are not equal.

A counter example would be a uni-axial straining flow, say $\mathbf u = x\hat{\mathbf x}-y\hat{\mathbf y}$. The stress tensor is
$$
\sigma = -p\mathbb I+\mu \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Clearly, $\sigma_{xx}-\sigma_{yy}\neq \sigma_{yy}-\sigma_{zz}$. Sometimes the normal stresses are interpreted as the stresses along the eigendirections of $\sigma$. Then the differences are differences between the eigenvalues. In this diagonal example it's equivalent.

However, in rheology a simple shear flow is often assumed. Let's say $\mathbf u=y\hat{\mathbf x}$. The Newtonian stress tensor is
$$
\sigma = -p\mathbb I+\frac{\mu}{2} \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Therefore, in this particular setup the normal stresses, in the sense "diagonal elements of $\sigma$", are zero. Note that in terms of the stresses along the principal directions, this matrix is equivalent (has the same eigenvalues) to the first example.